# Make discord.py bot react to emoji added in dm

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm trying to make a simple test bot that could do something when a reaction is added to a message that the bot send to the user dm. Now I'm stuck after the intial trigger that send the dm and add the emoji to react to. Any help to make that work?

```
import discord
import time


client = discord.Client()
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

@client.event
async def on_ready():
     print("testing")


@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    message_id = payload.message_id
    if message_id == 968972405206827028:
        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, client.guilds)
 
        if payload.emoji.name == '✅':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='role')
            user = await client.fetch_user(payload.user_id)
            embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Some order", description='Welcome to your order, %s \n Please select your payment method of choice:' % (payload.member.name), color=0x00ff00)
            dm = await user.send(embed=embedVar)
            await dm.add_reaction(some_emoji)
            await dm.add_reaction(some_emoji)


client.run("MY_TOKEN")
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly is not working and what the expected behaviour is? Also, please [edit] your question to include an [mcve] in the case that you're running into any issues.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Do you want this to trigger when the reaction is added within a guild, or a message? Or in a DM as well? Should the bot respond to DMs? A command with `wait_for` might be what you want. It may be better to also just say what are you trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying to get a particular guild from the payload `guild_id` attribute, which in a DM doesn't exist.

In discord.py, DMs aren't considered guilds, hence there is no particular ID. If you're setting this system up for a particular server, I'd recommend you use something as `client.get_guild(your_id_here)`, which will give you the `Guild` object if the bot is in that guild.

In short terms, `guild_id` is invalid since DMs are not guilds (servers). Find a way to work around that.

My solutions would be:

- is it for a specific server? **Get the guild by ID and perform your operations**
- is it for any server? **Perhaps use databases to store IDs and perform accordingly**

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your awnser, but when you message someone it does seems to have an id associate to it as you can copy them inside a dm conversation if you right click as dev mod, what's that?

Comment: DM channels do have their own channel ids and you can `get_channel` them. It's also probably a bad idea to use raw events. They're intended for when you don't need things that are needed in the cache (guild info, members, etc)

Comment: @EricJin Messages sent before the bot is started would be out of cache, and so reactions to those messages would not be detected through a non-raw event, no?

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs Then you still wouldn't be able to access the things you want to access, such as the message.